# My bathroom door drags when I close it

Tags: bathroom, doors

The door drags and doesn’t shut properly. The screw at the top of the hinge is loose. When I try to tighten it the screw just turns instead of tightens. I’ve tried putting toothpicks and wood glue in the hole as well as using a larger screw but nothing has worked.

Comment: Your focus on a single screw sounds odd. Are there adjacent screws holding the hinge leaf tight to the underlying surface still? Are you sure that the door itself isn't sagging? Hinges typically have one long screw that anchors into structural framing. Is the failing screw longer than the adjacent screws? Images would be helpful.

Comment: About the only way that the toothpicks and/or larger screw does not work is if the wood itself is split.  All the screws in the top hinge would need to be loose also, if that is the cause of the dragging.  Pictures of the hinge and the door will help.

Comment: Regarding the loose screw: is that into the door or the jamb? Is the screw closer to the hinge barrel or further away? (As noted, a pic or two would help.)

Comment: Is this a new problem? Has there been any change to the floor covering? The dragging could be a hinge issue, could be a flooring issue, could be a structural issue, or it could be that the door simply needs trimming because it was not sized properly when installed.

Comment: Are you supporting the door as you try the toothpicks and glue trick?